# understanding height vh in chrome vs safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm trying to understand code. This code does not work in safari and I found a warning sign with my height: 30vh

```
.scrolledTable{
  height: 30vh;
  overflow: auto;
  clear: both;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}
```

html

```
<div class = "scrolledTable">
   <table>---my table---</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost all modern desktop browser [support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) support `vh` unit.

Comment: Hey, May I know what is the warning?
This might help solving the issue
https://gist.github.com/pburtchaell/e702f441ba9b3f76f587

Comment: it's in the **height: 30vh** theres little yellow warning icon like it's not supposed like that
@VinitDesai

Comment: Can you attach screenshot as a part of your question?

Comment: thanks for ur response,.. red arrow, https://paste.pics/d88c880eac4be5bdf001847135b67808 @VinitDesai

Comment: what version of safari are you using?

Comment: it is version 5.1.7 (?) i use it from my old pc... and this is actually windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple stopped supporting Safari on Windows in 2013.

Support for the `vh` unit was added in Sarai 6.1.

Safari 6 was never released for Windows.

Your version of Safari is too old to support viewport units.

Comment: so the option is we have a apple tools to develop in safari. bcs windows is not supported anymore